# If I autoload a module, do I still need to include it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a module called `KeyValidations` that relies on another module called `Crypt`. Here's the directory structure:

```
.
├── lib
|   └── my_modules
|      ├── crypt.rb
|      └── key_validations.rb
```

I've added the following line to my `application.rb` so it should be autoloading everything in `lib/`:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

### The question

Since I'm autoloading everything in `lib`, do I still need to add `include MyModules::Crypt` before using it? I've tried accessing `Crypt` directly in `rails console` and it fails, with the message:

> LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Crypt, expected /var/www/dev/whitepayments.com/White/lib/my_modules/crypt.rb to define it

When I run `include MyModules::Crypt` before it, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]` means that it is not needed to `require my_modules/crypt.rb` into your environment.  However  `include MyModules::Crypt` means that within given context (e.g. class or a module) module methods will be included. If a module is required within environment,  it is not equal that its methods are also loaded. That is why `include` (or `extend`, depending on scope) is necessary here.

Comment: So even with autoloading, I would still need to `include` it?

Comment: By extending `config.autoload_paths` with some extra directories, you only load modules into your environment. The're known and might be accessed, e.g. `MyModules::Crypt`. Without autoloading you'll get `uninitialized constant MyModules`. `include` is completely different, because it includes module methods into whatever you want. Even including within rails console, e.g. `MyModules::Crypt`, includes module methods into `Object` class (check `self.class` within console).

Comment: Last but not least, by requiring some module within another module/class, it is not equal to declare: 'I want these module methods to use here'. Once module is required (or loaded actually), it is accessible by its name, but that's all. To include it into another module/class `include`/`extend` has to be used.